# Log(ger) Variable Declaration

Tags: java, logging

In the majority of cases I see `Log` instances declared as follows:

```
public static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
```

I assume this means that the *log configuration* is loaded when the `MyClass` is loaded and is therefore set in stone until the `MyClass` is either reloaded or the JVM restarted?

So, if this assumption is correct what is the best way to ensure changes to the *log configuration* are picked up as (or as soon after) they happen?

Comment: Are you using `commons-logging`, judging by the `LogFactory` class? What is your underlying implementation

Comment: Yes, the example was commons-logging, but it was meant to be a more general question - I'd be interested in commons-logging and Log4J.

Comment: my search for "log4j reload configuration" gets several interesting hits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are using `commons-logging` from the `LogFactory` class? As far as I know, none of the usual logging implementations (Log4J, `java.util.logging`) allow you to reload a configuration file in a running application (regardless of whether the actuall `Logger`s are declared as `static` variables). (**EDIT**: *Peter's answer below proves that I was wrong about this in the case of Log4J*)

However, they do allow for the *dynamic changing of logging levels* (e.g. via an `MBean`). These level-changes will be picked up by *any* `Logger` (including those declared as static variables). If you use `java.util.logging` you get the `MBean` for free in the `JConsole`.

Is it just the changing of levels you care about, or do you wish to provide completely different logging configurations (e.g. files, logger definitions) *on the fly*?

Comment: Yes, it'd just be the logging levels that I'd want to change so I'll take a closer look at the MBean route.

Comment: It's actually extremely easy to add a Log4J / `j.u.l` "bridge" which means that you can use the `j.u.l` MBeans to manage your Log4J loggers

Comment: Log4j will reload your config file whenever it changes, if you so desire. see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this depends on the underlying implementation, as pointed out by oxbow_lanes. Generally, it might be difficult to reconfigure your logging subsystem if you are relying on config files that are available via the classpath. To get around this limitation, we do all our config programmatically, and do not rely on only static config files. But I don't know whether your implementation support programmatic reconfiguration.

Answer (score 2):

No, the log configuration is loaded typically when the logging implementation classes are initialized. When your class is (re)loaded, all that happens is that the logging API is called to get a logger (which may or may not be present in any configuration) and stored as a class variable.

To reload your logging configuration, then you typically would have to get the logging implementation to reload.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the backend.

Logback has a very niftly feature where the reload can be triggered by JMX, i.e. in jvisualvm or jconsole.

Comment: Recent version of logback added an auto-scan feature which is even cooler. http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you are using "java.util.logging" logging directly, then you CAN reload the logger configurations on the fly.  There are two methods on the LogManager class for doing this:

```
public void readConfiguration() 
    throws IOException, SecurityException
```

This reloads the default logging properties and reinitializes the logging configuration.

```
public void readConfiguration(InputStream ins)
    throws IOException, SecurityException
```

This loads the logging properties from a stream (in Property file format) and reinitializes the logging configuration.

See the [LogManager javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).

Answer (score 1):

Log4j can reload your config file whenever it changes.

see the faq [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#3.6)

> Is there a way to get log4j to
>   automatically reload a configuration
>   file if it changes?
>
> Yes. Both the DOMConfigurator and the
>   PropertyConfigurator support automatic
>   reloading through the
>   configureAndWatch method. See the API
>   documentation for more details.
>
> Because the configureAndWatch launches
>   a separate wathdog thread, and because
>   there is no way to stop this thread in
>   log4j 1.2, the configureAndWatch
>   method is unsafe for use in J2EE
>   envrironments where applications are
>   recycled.